# js for loop innerHTML function does not work on load on same id

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

for loop innerHTML += does not work when function is called on addeventlistener load

```
<main id='outSecs'>
    foobar
</main>

<script>
    document.getElementById('outSecs').addEventListener('load', myFn);

    function myFn() {
        for (var q = 1; q <= 9; q++) {
            document.getElementById('outSecs').innerHTML += "<section><p class='myOutput'></p></section>";
        }
    }
```

how do i insert looped code with innerHTML on load?

Comment: Put the event listener on `window`; that's where the "load" event is fired. (Perhaps `document` would work too; try whichever you prefer.)

Comment: Just tested: `document.addEventListener("load",fn)` does not work but `window.addEventListener("load",fn)`does. Otherwise: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",fn)` would be an alternative.

Comment: You should avoid patterns like `.innerHTML +=` since they cause the DOM to be reconstructed each time. This can bring down the page performance. Instead try to build an array with the HTML parts, `.join("")` them afterwards and assign them with  `.innerHTML=` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use window's DOMContentLoaded event.

Also No need to keep getting the main container every time. Just get it once and fill it.

Here is an updated version using ES6 and template literals

```js
const myFn = () => {
  const mainContainer = document.getElementById('outSecs');
  mainContainer.innerHTML = Array.from({ length: 9 })
  .map((_, i) => `<section id="s${i}"><p class="myOutput">${i+1}</p></section>`)
  .join('')
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myFn);
```

```html
<main id='outSecs'>
  foobar
</main>
```